# How to remove Ubuntu 18.04 from dual boot when both are ubuntu and set up on differnet partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have ubuntu 18.04 on one partition & disco dingo on another partition. I have deleted all files from the 18.04 partition because I had problems starting up 18.04. Now , I can access disco dingo , but on grub menu it shows the option to boot it from 18.04 , after selecting that it shows missing file. It makes start up of the PC time consuming. I want to directly start with disco dingo . Is there ANYWAY ?

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: actually I removed the kernels I am not using first then updated the grub , and then the option to boot into 18.04 came. But still it boots into the grub menu first, but I want it to boot directly without first showing grub menu.Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: If you have only 19.04 but the Grub menu still shows the older version it means you're in UEFI mode and those entries are still there. You may need to use `efibootmgr`

Comment: no I am in 19.04 and it doesn't show any older version now. but I don't want to see the grub menu every time I switch on my PC. what to do?

Comment: I think you have to edit grub.conf and set timeout to zero...